# How make InputStreamReader fail on invalid data for encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, inputstreamreader

I have some bytes which should be UTF-8 encoded, but which may contain a text is ISO8859-1 encoding, if the user somehow didn't manage to use his text editor the right way.

I read the file with an InputStreamReader:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( 
    new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

But every time the user uses umlauts like "ä", which are invalid UTF-8 when stored in ISO8859-1 the InputStreamReader does not complain but adds placeholder characters.

Is there is simple way to make this throw an Exception on invalid input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(file), decoder);
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there was an API to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `.newDecoder()`:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( 
    new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder());
```